# Is there any IDE where I can debug C and Python codes simultaneously?

Tags: c, python-3.x, vscode-debugger

I want to build a system, in which I want to use both Python and C. Python will be used for GUI on wxPython module and C will be used to handle backend processes. I have some pre-built C functions which will be rearranged and sent to a C compiler as files by the GUI. After compilation is done, the resulting file will be given as an argument to another executable and run the executable.

I've tried to run some exe from inside Python. Now I'm looking for an IDE which supports working with both the languages simultaneously i.e. coding and debugging.

Comment: Visual Studio supports debugging both Python and C++.

Comment: VSCode will support both as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many IDE where you can debug C and Python codes simultaneously. You can choose any form the list bellow

[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/)

[Visualstudio](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/)

[Zeus Ide](https://www.zeusedit.com/index.html)

Comment: I have started working with VS code. Is it ok?

Comment: VS code and eclipse is my personal favorite,

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Eclipse. You can install Python and C/C++ on it.

Comment: Yes, same here. Eclipse will help you.

Comment: Eclipse is a memory eating monstrosity ...